# Can I block executing a certain flow in a sandbox env?

Tags: sandbox-clone

We have a scheduled flow which we do not want to be invoked in the sandbox.

Is it possible in any way to prevent that ?

- manual option would be to just 'Deactivate' the flow
- like soql: SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization LIMIT 1
  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual option indeed would be to deactivate the flow in the sandbox.

Automated solution :
Add a getRecord element in the flow to query `Organization` object and choose to fetch only the first record.
Then use a decision element that reads the variable returned by getRecord and if `isSandbox` field equals to false, then proceed with the rest of the flow logic. This option means that the flow won't execute in **any** Sandbox